# Different values of different RFID readers

Tags: rfid

I have two different RFID readers which both give different outputs.
One RFID readers is this one from dealextreme:
http://dx.com/p/intelligent-id-card-usb-reader-174455
It is plug and play.
Of the other reader I only have the program which we use to generate the code which is HidIdMonitor.exe

The first one generates the following code:
0221365003

The second one generates the following code:
010d31c30b

The problem is that I cannot find any form to convert one code to the other. Is there anyone who can tell me how to convert this, or what the code is based on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the same value. Hex and Decimal!!

```
 0221365003 = decimal
 D31C30B = hex (010 is a prefix)
```

Comment: Thanks, the prefix was causing the problem.

Comment: Valid answer then? ;)

Comment: Then I have another question. How do you determine the prefix. Because when I use another token the prefix is: 2a00
With the following token numbers: hex: 2a002bb8ae dec:0002865326

Comment: I think it might be the type of token, since the same type of token give the same prefix.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have these devices and I've only seen the decimal form:( . However, there is a gap (zeroes) between the beginning of the code and the actual hex value, so it seems it's some sort of vendor ID or token. Probably you should only use the last 8 characters, since is the 32 bits.